# What is WM ASF Writer and where can I download it

Tags: writer, asf

I got a program and it returns the error WM ASF Writer not found. I searched for it online and it gave me links of how to use it when writing code. Does anyone know where I can download this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Windows Media ASF Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a DirectShow filter and should already be part of your OS (assuming Windows XP SP3, Win 7 or Windows 2008 with Desktop Extensions enabled)

The filter is also part of the [Windows Media™ Format SDK](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/c/3/ac367925-39e7-4451-a175-a224f94fbdce/wmformat11sdk.exe)

Comment: I don't already have it and I need it. Do you or for that matter anyone, know where I can download it from.

Comment: @carstorm there is a direct download link for the WM Format SDK in my answer.